# checkbox checking lost during polling with a4j:poll

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

In my jsf page, there is a table using rich:dataTable, each row of table has a h:selectBoolenCheckbox, I want to use it to check some rows and then click a button to trigger action only for the checked rows.
And also there is a4j:poll component used in this page, every 15 seconds the table data will be refreshed. After that problem is coming:
my a4j:poll will invoke an action to load the latest data, the loading time need 2-4 seconds. If I click some checkbox to select some rows during the loading period, the checked checkbox will be lost after loading finish.
So do you met the same problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: In future questions please always mention exact JSF impl/version and also the one of any component library you're using. It makes giving a more detailed answer easier as there may be differences in the approach depending on the version used.

Comment: I used jsf1.2 with richfaces 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't update the whole table. Update *only* the cells which really need to be updated. You can use EL in `reRender` (RF 3.x) or `render` (RF 4.x) attribute of `<a4j:poll>` to dynamically populate a spaceseparated string of client IDs of all cells.

Comment: In my case, the checkbox also need to reRender in each polling, since it may change disabled status according the action executing result.